# View Photos in Certain Folder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am saving my photos to a custom folder `Documents/Photos/XXFOLDERNAME`. Everything saves correctly.

How can my user view these photos in that folder in a format like the calendar roll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do so. You have to build a UI to do this. Here is a project that may help you out.

https://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer